# Using @import of XCode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, import, xcode5

I was trying to use @import feature of XCode 5. I have replaced all #imports with @import for all iOS frameworks. Also, in Project settings I have enabled “Enable Modules (C and Objective C).

But then when I remove UIKit framework from my project, I start getting compilation errors.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: What are the errors? Linker errors, etc?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to explicitly replace `#import` all over the replace... Xcode will take care of it for you if you set `enable modules` to `YES` on your project target.

Comment: Do you also have `Link Frameworks Automatically` set to `YES` on your project target's build settings?

Comment: Yes I am getting the link errors and have already tried the link shared by JRG-Developer. I tried putting @import and even with that I am getting compilation errors. Checked "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" and "Link Frameworks Automatically" and they are set properly. Also, I am doing this on an already existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you add `@import UIKit` and `@import Foundation`?

I ran a quick test. I removed UIKit and Foundation from the "Link Binary with Libraries" pane, and @import'd in my `app-Prefix.pch` precompiled header file. It worked like a charm. Try the @import statements there, for any of your "global" libraries.

Other than that, I do have "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" and "Link Frameworks Automatically" turned on, but that was out of the box, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I tried putting @import and even with that I am getting compilation errors. Checked "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" and "Link Frameworks Automatically" and they are set properly. Also, I am doing this on an already existing project.

Comment: @Abhinav where are you putting the `@import` statements? Specifically, what file?

Comment: I am putting it inside MyProject_Prefix.pch file.

Comment: This cannot work in the pch file... this is not a precompiler directive.